# to get the unique records

Tags: ubuntu, csv

I have the below csv file for each day in month.
I need unique count of users from this. we need monthly count.

```
"DATE","TIME","User Type","User ID","IP Address","Host Name"
"2019-06-01","00:02:08,278","User","uid=robot_th,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.120.134.13","10.120.134.13"
"2019-06-01","00:02:08,918","User","uid=robot_th,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.120.134.13","10.120.134.13"
"2019-06-01","00:03:16,143","User","uid=josebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.121.21.98","10.121.21.98"
"2019-06-01","00:05:14,314","User","uid=josebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.121.21.107","10.121.21.107"
"2019-06-01","00:06:34,080","User","uid=robot_sebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.121.21.107","10.121.21.107"
"2019-06-01","00:16:54,981","User","uid=robot_sebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.121.21.98","10.121.21.98"
"2019-06-01","00:16:55,575","User","uid=robot_sebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.121.21.98","10.121.21.98"
"2019-06-01","00:17:26,344","User","uid=jolivier,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.120.134.13","10.120.134.13"
"2019-06-01","00:17:30,994","User","uid=robot_th,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.120.134.13","10.120.134.13"
"2019-06-01","00:18:16,914","User","uid=robot_sebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.121.21.98","10.121.21.98"
"2019-06-01","00:31:48,322","User","uid=josebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.121.21.98","10.121.21.98"
"2019-06-01","00:32:25,260","User","uid=robot_th,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.120.134.13","10.120.134.13"
"2019-06-01","00:32:57,631","User","uid=josebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.121.21.98","10.121.21.98"
"2019-06-01","00:35:11,292","User","uid=josebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.121.21.107","10.121.21.107"
"2019-06-01","00:46:58,693","User","uid=robot_sebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.121.21.98","10.121.21.98"
"2019-06-01","00:47:01,215","User","uid=robot_th,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be","10.120.134.13","10.120.134.13"
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: i have tried  this: <EPNY_LOGINS2020-07-31.csv grep '^[^,]*,[^,]*,people' | cut -d, -f2 | sort | uniq -c

Comment: why don't you redirect that to a file, and use python pandas to load the file and count. It will take 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

In [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), you can run

```
mlr --csv count-distinct -f "User ID" input.csv
```

to have

```
+----------------------------------------+-------+
| User ID                                | count |
+----------------------------------------+-------+
| uid=robot_th,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be     | 5     |
| uid=josebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be     | 5     |
| uid=robot_sebeco,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be | 5     |
| uid=jolivier,ou=people,o=kpno,c=be     | 1     |
+----------------------------------------+-------+
```